# How can I replace special characters from string?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string like this:

```
"https://myEnv.site.org/search?q=searchTerm"
```

I am trying to get the searchterm.

and I succeded somewhat with this:

```
const returnValue = url
  .split('=')[1]
  .replace('+', ' ');
```

The replace is for when there is a space, like for example when value is `SearchTerm withSpace`

Im some scenarios I also have this charachter in the searchterm:

```
Something® Category® version subversion somethingElse
```

This turn into:

```
 Something%C2%+Category%C2%+version+subversion+somethingElse
```

I thought I could solve it by doing this:

```
const returnValue = url
  .split('=')[1]
  .replace('%C2%AE', '®')
  .replace('+', ' ');
```

Problem is that it only removes the first instance, the new value becomes:

```
Something® Category%C2%+version+subversion+somethingElse
```

I have tried a few regex attempts and Ive gotten this far which gives me the wrong result:

```
const returnValue = url
  .split('=')[1]
  .replace(/([~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,.\/? ])+/g, '®')
  .replace(/^(-)+|(-)+$/g, ' ');
```

To be clear I want to replace `%C2%AE` with `®` and the `+` with `' '`

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? `new URL("https://myEnv.site.org/search?q=Something%AE%20Category%AE%20version%20subversion%20somethingElse").searchParams.get("q")`

Comment: To directly address just the question asked, you need to decode the URI component. Use the global function decodeURIComponent.

Comment: returnValue=url.replaceAll('%C2%', '®').replaceAll('+', ' ');

Comment: If you work on NodeJS use their URL class, in Browser Javascript it is the same code using window.URL:

```js
const test = "https://myEnv.site.org/search?q=searchTerm+2"

console.log(new URL(test).searchParams.get('q'))
# output: searchTerm 2
```

This will parse the URL and decode the html encoded sting in one go.

Comment: @lbragile yes, if you have the querystring

Comment: @ibragile new URLSearchParams(url).get('q') did not work. I got "Cannot read property 'charAt' of null"